# How to get the highest number in a returned Linq query result?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table called Picture in my database. I'm using the primary key of that table as the filenames for the pictures.

When creating a new picture I need it to follow a logical sequence. For this I'm using the primary key.

How can I get the highest value of the primary key for this table?

Picture table has these columns: ID, IDProject (foreign key). I just need to get the highest ID number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`Enumerable.Max()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) method, which "returns the maximum value in a sequence of values." For example, finding the highest picture ID:

```
int pictureId = pictures.Max(p => p.ID);
```

Also, see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386972.aspx) on MSDN ("Find the Maximum Value in a Numeric Sequence").

Answer (score 3):

I would guess either of the following two should work:

```
source.Max(e => e.ID)
```

or:

```
source.OrderByDescending(e => e.ID).First();
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using the second one over the first?

Comment: It might be that the database will optimize it better, depends on the data source really.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`Enumerable.Max`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx):

```
// pictures is IEnumerable<Picture>
int max = pictures.Max(x => x.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxID = query.Max(e => e.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the extension method `IEnumerable.Max`.

so in your case it will be something like this:

```
pictureList.Max( p => p.ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var record = myDataSet.OrderByDescending(o => o.ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted; this is the only answer so far that properly accounts for the boundary case of no records present and it is likely to produce a good query when transformed to SQL.  ORDER DESC should be very efficient for a primary key, as is TOP.

Comment: @Dan Bryant, I couldn't agree more.